# getrawtransaction is error bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I use VPS centos 7, and i install bitcoind follow: 
https://www.ringingliberty.com/bitcoin/

this is file bitcoin.conf:

```
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=My_password
daemon=1
rpctimeout=30
rpcport=8332
gen=0
txindex=1
keypool=100
```

Then i ran: `bitcoind -reindex -deamon` then ran:
`bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction string_txid`

i get error:

```
error code: -5
error message:
No information available about transaction
```

I use: Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.13.0.0-ga402396

I don't know wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That will success when bitcoind download all blockchain.

Wait till bitcoind complete synchronization then try again.

Comment: But, i ran same code on VPS of my friend. It run ok? Why?

Comment: Maybe your friend's node is synced and yours is not?